# How to create an array of N floats values with fold expression?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, function-templates, fold-expression

Suppose the following function

```cpp
template<size_t N>
constexpr std::array<float, N> make_ones()
{
    std::array<float, N> ret{};
    for (size_t k = 0; k != N; ++k)
    {
        ret[k] = 1.0f;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Is it possible to write that with a fold expression?
The problem is that I do not have a pack to expand.

Comment: No. With recursive template -maybe../ but why not `std::fill`

Comment: This isn’t about **fold** expressions, just pack expansion (and the common problem of how to create a pack).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie std::fill is only constexpr since C++20

Comment: Why do you ask? This array initialization is evaluated once at compile time (and pretty fast).  So what makes you think about fold expressions? (these are for parameter packs as you already note)

Comment: In C++20 or later, `constexpr` -> `consteval` to be absolutely certain that the array is filled at compile time (else compiler error will ensue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to write that with a fold expression?

Not with *fold expression* but *pack expansion* as well as with *[index sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)*, in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you could do:

```
template <size_t N>
constexpr std::array<float, N> make_ones()
{
    return []<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::array<float, sizeof...(Is)>{( static_cast<void>(Is), 1.0f)...};
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

***[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9686vvP5x)***

---

For compilers that doesn't support C++20 or later, you might do

```
template <size_t... Is>
constexpr std::array<float, sizeof...(Is)> make_ones_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::array<float, sizeof...(Is)>{(static_cast<void>(Is), 1.0f)...};
}

template<size_t N>
constexpr std::array<float, N> make_ones()
{
    return make_ones_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Comment: Kudos, but, ehm, I know that readability is subjective, but I'd freak out if I had to review this. Do you consider the intent of this code explicit?

Comment: @MatG So would I.

Comment: @MatG It is common pattern for stuff like that. If you're unfamiliar with template metaprogramming you won't be able to read any generic code anyway(no matter how explicit it is). You can have a look at Haskel code, it is pure alien language until you learn it in details.

Comment: @MatG See the explanation here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bGe3M7KG5

Comment: @MatG Would it help you to recognise the pattern, if made a bit more [generic](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fq13YGqzP)? I don't know how common it is in the wild, but you can find examples of its use in some Q&A here and other cpp resources available online.